# Javascript Overlay/Dialog Tracking with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, jquery-dialog

Using javascript (jQuery to be precise in my case) I need to enable a dialog box to be tracked in Google Analytics as a unique page view, despite it being only a modal overlay.

For context purposes I dont want the user leaving the page and the dialog content is loaded in via an ajax call.

Comment: Would recording event suffice? Or do you need it to be an full page view?

Comment: ill be honest my knowledge of GA is somewhat pants. Expanding on my use case I need the products on the site to load in the dialog modal overlay. The category page you load a product from needs to be the page the user stays on.

Tracking the products needs to 'work' just like any other page on the site.

Comment: So, are you looking for multiple page views to take place in a modal window, depending on clicks of items inside of it? What kind of DOM elements would you be using? It's usually easiest to associate those loads with the clicks on the links.

Comment: I want to try and stay as close to the basic "load a page, it registers a the view, you click another page it registers another view" model as possible; Your question @yc does raise the issue of what happens when someone closes the dialog (a product page in my use case), does this constitute a new view of the category page. 

Also if I bind the left right arrow keys it will load the previous or next product, respectively. This should register the pageview with GA. The binding would trigger a new ajax request for the next/previous product html.

Comment: If you follow the model of: Your regular HTML pages all contain a single trackPageview call, and each binding that changes to another modal page also tracks another pageview, as long as you don't bind it as such on the 'close' action on the modal, there wouldn't be an 'extra' page view for the background category page, since that page will not need to load from scratch, and thus won't trigger a new trackPageview call.

Comment: cheers. Will give this a go and feedback.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're using Google Analytics new async code, all you need to do is place this code in the JavaScript block where you render your modal dialog.

```
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/fake/modal/path/here']);
```

If you're using the old code,

```
   pageTracker._trackPageview('/fake/modal/path/here');
```

---

The basic gist of this is you should attach the _trackPageview call anywhere you're binding an event event that changes the modal. If you're doing this for multiple modal pageviews, you'll need to either manually code each internal modal page, or programmatically name them. If these modal changes trigger changes in the URL's hash, you could try this approach: [Tracking Anchor Links in Goal Funnels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564733)

Comment: Cool. When you say "where you render your modal dialog" do you mean in the html that triggers the dialog or within the returned html that makesup the dialog?

Comment: Either one (assuming you mean within <script> tags within the html), but I think the former is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/),  `ga.js` is now a legacy library. So if you are using the latest version of this library, which is `analytics.js`, then the response would be:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/fake/modal/path/here');
```