# Google Analytics inside Lightbox_me

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am using [**Lightbox_me**](http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/) to open a popup on pageload.

The popup has a Feedburner form, so I need to find a way on how to insert Google Analytics code, so each popup load is counted as a pageview in Google Analytics.

I appreciate any help in terms of how to insert GA inside **jquery.lightbox_me.js**

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code to evaluate possible solutions.

Comment: Edited to add more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*This can be solved in two ways. Use the option that best suit you.*

### Virtual Pageview

This is tracked as an additional page and will be available in the Behavior > Site Content report.

```
// Universal Analytics
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': '/fake/lightbox_me/path/',
  'title': 'Email Sign Up Lightbox'
});

 // Classic Google Analytics
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/fake/lightbox_me/path/']);
```

---

### Page Event

This is tracked as an event and will be available in the Behavior > Events report.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'modal', 'load', 'email signup', 3);
```

***Both of them can be placed in the function where you load the modal window.***

---

*References:*

http://www.websiteoptimizers.com/blog/8-fabulous-uses-of-google-analytics-events-tracking-to-better-understand-your-customers/

http://www.dirtyanalytics.com/virtual-pageviews-google-analytics/

[Javascript Overlay/Dialog Tracking with Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621966/javascript-overlay-dialog-tracking-with-google-analytics)

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that the lightbox is not loaded through any event like onclick or onsubmit etc...

The lightbox is loaded simply by calling 
    http://www.insurance-forums.net/forum/stickybar/modal/lightbox-me-cookie.js

So I need to find a way on how to insert GA code INSIDE this .js file

Comment: @valdroni what I see from your code is `jQuery('#sign_up_email').lightbox_me({`, right? You should put the GA code above in `onLoad: function() {`. When the modal shows up and it has focus then register the virtual pageview or the event.